# Doing UI task in doinbackground() in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Is there a way to do UI task in the doinbackground() of the AsyncTask. I am well aware it is better to do it in onPostExecute method. But in my case since I am need to use a reusable alert, being able to access the UI in my doinbackground would save me a lot of time. That is, I need to tweak the code in 46 places but being able to do this in the doinbackground will need the change in just one place.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html.

Comment: by the time you created this question and post here, you could easily write some code and check what happened.

Comment: You can define and initialize a Handler in your activity and from doInBackGround, just send an empty message to this handler. Even to achieve this, you need to pass Activity context to your AsyncTask

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Hope this will solve your problem

```
    onPreExecute() {
       // some code #1
    }

    doInBackground() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // some code #3 (Write your code here to run in UI thread)

                    }
                });
    }

    onPostExecute() {
       // some code #3
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Other than updating UI from `onPostExecute()`, there are 2 ways to update UI:

1. From `doInBackground()` by implementing `runOnUiThread()`
2. From `onProgressUpdate()`

FYI,

`onProgressUpdate()` - Whenever you want to update anything from `doInBackground()`, You just need to use `publishProgress(Progress...)` to publish one or more units of progress, it will ping `onProgressUpdate()` to update on UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You gt my problem. Will try runOnUiThread(). onProgressUpdate() would get tedious again :)

Comment: I disagree with an usage of runOnUiThread in doInBackround(), its sux and it brokes main purpose of background processing.

Comment: @Sajmon sorry I don't agree with you and that depends on how you implement `runOnUiThread()` inside `doInBackground()`

Answer (score 3):

you could utilize `onProgressUpdate` rather

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29)