# Where/how to set values for ArrayList<object> in GridView in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-imageview, android-gridview

I am having trouble trying to understand how to set values for a data object in `Asynctask`.  From several readings I've found that I cannot set values in the `doInBackground()` portion of the `Asynctask`. With that said, I'm stumped as where to set them. I know the values are present by doing checks, but when I try to set the `urlTuxName/urlTuxPhoto` values in `onPostExecute` by doing `milTuxs.urlTuxName/urlTuxPhoto`, these variables aren't recognized. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
private class LoadImageTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<Tuxedo>, Void, ArrayList<TuxLoader>> {

    private String name;
    Bitmap imageBitmap;
    ArrayList<TuxLoader> milTuxs = new ArrayList<TuxLoader>();


    @Override
    protected ArrayList<TuxLoader> doInBackground(ArrayList<Tuxedo>... tuxList) {

        ArrayList<Tuxedo> t = tuxList[0];
        System.out.println("tuxUrlList count =" + t.size());
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            for(int i=0; i< t.size(); i++) {

                Tuxedo tempList = t.get(i);
                URL imageUrl = new URL(tempList.tuxUrlPath);


                imageBitmap = DecodeBitmapSampleSize(imageUrl, 70, 70);

                addBitmapToMemoryCache(String.valueOf(imageUrl), imageBitmap);

                name = tempList.tuxName;
                //System.out.println("Tux name is " + name);

                TuxLoader tuxLoad = new TuxLoader();

                                tuxLoad.urlName = name;
                                tuxLoad.bitmap = imageBitmap;
                //tuxLoad.urlTuxName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_label);
                //tuxLoad.urlTuxName.setText(name);
                //tuxLoad.urlPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
                //tuxLoad.urlPhoto.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

                milTuxs.add(tuxLoad);
                //System.out.println("Mills Tuxs = " + milTuxs);
            }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("error", "Image Download Failed");
                //t.bitmap = null;
                imageBitmap = null;
        }
          return milTuxs;
    }   


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<TuxLoader> milTuxs) {
        super.onPostExecute(milTuxs);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        System.out.println("PexMills Tuxs = " + milTuxs);
        //Set tuxGrid as the GridView variable
        GridView tuxGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.tux_grid_view);
        CustomAdapterGrid4 adapter = (new CustomAdapterGrid4(TuxedoActivity2.this, milTuxs));
        tuxGrid.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set values in doInBackground [**directly**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15757788/3134811). Anyways, the reason that it doesn't work is you are assigning the values in your for loop, it changes the value every time. So try the method from the link above ([just in case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15757788/3134811)). Also i have to ask, how many values going to be setted to urlTextName/urlPhoto?

Comment: Actually the values are being added properly to ArrayList<milTuxs> and  it's a total of 40 values.  Originally 20 but since there are two items in the data object, it comes to 40.

Comment: I mean this part  `but when I try to set the urlTuxName/urlTuxPhoto values in onPostExecute by doing milTuxs.urlTuxName/urlTuxPhoto, these variables aren't recognized`. Try it in the doInBackground with the link i posted

Comment: Ok will do, but won't this hold up the main UI?

Comment: Of course its not the perfect solution, there is more safe ways like using onProgressUpdate etc. But it won't cause too much problems if you don't use it a lot. Also i don't know your TuxLoader class so i can't make comment about that.