# How to change progressDialog text

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

i have an asynctask but if i implement a Thread.Sleep , then my app crashes , i dont know  why, in onPreExecute i can see my first message and then after two secs it appears the other one i put in doInBackground  , but its not working

```
private class sendMail extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            dialog.show();

        }

        // automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            dialog.setMessage("Downloading files...");

            new BackgroundTask().execute();

//MY DOWNLOADING METHODS STUFF
```

And then i dismiss this dialog somewhere else

Log

> An error occurred while executing doInBackground()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the UI elements from a background thread you can update the progressbar in `onProgressUpdate`, most importantly you need to `publishProgress(value)` in doInBackground and update using `onProgressUpdate`. Read more about the AsyncTask [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Example code:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            for (; count <= params[0]; count++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    publishProgress(count);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return "Task Completed.";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                txt.setText(result);
                btn.setText("Restart");
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            txt.setText("Task Starting...");
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            txt.setText("Running..."+ values[0]);
            progressBar.setMessage("Downloading files...");
            progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: dude , this is a progress bar and im working with progress dialog, also please refer from where you paste that code because i already saw that tutorial page

Comment: dude, both are UI elements and yes I copied the code from the web to show you an example and it is not mandatory to provide the link unless there is more detailed information which I can't explain here. If you can read my answer properly you will find the answers, also I can see someone else also answered the same. I would suggest you read about "Accessing UI elements from AsyncTask" and please note anything which is shown graphically in an Activity are care UI elements including progress dialog which can only be accessed from UI Thread. I am really trying to help you and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Use UI thread to show dialog message in doInBackground refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15757788/6626966